# jQuery display div on scroll on desktop

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using the below code to make turn my hidden div to display:block when the user scrolls 800px down the page.

The code is working exactly as it should when displaying the webpage on a mobile device, but when display on laptop/desktop the code isn't working/div doesn't become visible. Can anyone point me in the direction as to why this is?

JQUERY:

```
<script>
     $(document).scroll(function() {
       var y = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (y > 800) {
         $('#topholder').fadeIn();
       } else {
         $('#topholder').fadeOut();
       }
     });
     </script>
```

CSS:

```
#topholder{
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 30px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 25%;
  color: ghostwhite;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#top"><div id="topholder">&uarr;</div></a>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Works here https://jsfiddle.net/h8uzn1mo/3/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason was due to having `overflow-x:hidden` applied to my body div. Removing that and the div displays as should when scrolled.
Thanks guys